# Order of JSON elements while partly copying it from another JSON in Javascript

Tags: json

I have a source JSON object like this:

```
{
   "Toys": [
        {
            "id": "ABCD",
            "type": "1"
        },
        {
            "name": "EFGH",
            "price": 100"
        },
        {
            "shop": "IJKL",
            "location": "1234"
        }

    ]
}
```

And I need the Final JSON to be like this:

```
{
    "Toys": [
        {
            "links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "https:MY URL/ABCD"
                }
            },
            "id": "ABCD",
            "type": "1"
        },
        {
            "links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "https:MY URL/EFGH"
                }
            },
            "name": "EFGH",
            "price": 100"
        },
        {
            "links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "https:MY URL/IJKL"
                }
            },
            "shop": "IJKL",
            "location": "1234"
        }
    ]
}
```

Also, I NEED TO maintain the ORDER of the elements (First href and then toys) as requested. Any idea how can I do that in Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following approach:

```
var json = {
   "Toys": [
        {
            "id": "ABCD",
            "type": "1"
        },
        {
            "name": "EFGH",
            "price": 100
        },
        {
            "shop": "IJKL",
            "location": "1234"
        }

    ]
};


var data = {"Toys":[]};
for (var i=0; i< json.Toys.length; i++) {
    var keys = Object.keys(json.Toys[i]);
    var url = "https://stackoverflow.com/" + json.Toys[i][keys[0]];
    var toy = {
        "links": {
            "self": {
                "href": url
            }
        }
    };
    for (var j=0; j< keys.length; j++) {
      toy[keys[j]] = json.Toys[i][keys[j]];
    }
    data.Toys.push(toy);
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

---

**result:**

```
{
    "Toys": [{
        "links": {
            "self": {
                "href": "https://stackoverflow.com/ABCD"
            }
        },
        "id": "ABCD",
        "type": "1"
    }, {
        "links": {
            "self": {
                "href": "https://stackoverflow.com/EFGH"
            }
        },
        "name": "EFGH",
        "price": 100
    }, {
        "links": {
            "self": {
                "href": "https://stackoverflow.com/IJKL"
            }
        },
        "shop": "IJKL",
        "location": "1234"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I cant take this approach due to the fact that the Key of the elements in the source are dynamic. Sometimes, they are id and type, some time, name and price or shp and location. Also, I need something in javascript.

Comment: The list is quite big and number of elements also varries. So, I do not think fix number of key based approach would work here. So I would prefer to have a copy-paste option along with the href. Can you suggest in this line ?

Comment: I can only give you pointers, if the json structure varies too much , you need to find a pattern and hack your way through, everything is possible although it could get messy

Comment: What about a copy paste based approach where in first the href would be added and then the rest would be copied from source and pasted in the final JSON object ? Any idea how to do that ?